# How to load local files (img) in RMarkdown with htmltools::includeHTML

Tags: javascript, html, r, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm rendering an HTML document via RMarkdown using:

```
htmltools::includeHTML("index.html")
```

My index.html is basically set up like this:

```
    <!-- Clicking the button changes the image displayed-->
    <label class="btn btn-default active" id="my_button">
          <input class="btn" type="radio" name="options" autocomplete="off" > This Displays Other Image
        </label>

    <div class="container" style="padding-bottom:0px">
      <div class="row" id="od-content">
        <div class="col-md-10"> 
            <h2 class="mb-3">Title</h2> 
                <p>
                   Blah blah blah
                </p>
                <p class="viz-photo">             
                    <div class="col-12"> 
                        <img class="img-fluid viz" src="img/image_1.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
                </p>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
     
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

In main.js, it's basically set up so that the HTML image changes when a button is pressed:

```
var special_content = '<div class="col-md-10">' + 
                            '<h2 class="mb-3">Special Title!</h2>' +    
                            '<p>' +
                                'Blah blah' +
                            '</p>' +
                            '<p class="viz-photo">' +             
                                '<div class="col-12">' + 
                                    '<img class="img-fluid viz" src="img/image_2.png" alt="Card image cap">' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</p>' +
                          '</div>' 


$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#my_button').on('click', function(e) {

  
  document.getElementById("od-content").innerHTML = special_content;
  });
});
```

So, if I render to HTML, the index.html shows the first image just fine.  But, when I click the button, the second image cannot be found (the one referenced in the javascript).  The javascript code is working because the text is updating.  It's only the image that is failing.
When I inspect img_1, I see:

[image]

When I inspect the broken image_2, I see that the src is still using the local "img" folder.

So, somehow, R Markdown is packaging the first image somehow to be self-contained, but not the second image?

Both images are local and stored in the `img` folder.  So, RMarkdown is able to render image_1 but not image_2.  My file structure is as follows:

```
My_Folder
    -img folder
         -image_1.png
         -image_2.png
    -CSS folder
    -js folder
         -main.js
    -index.html
    -my_rmarkdown.RMD
```

I've also tried this with no luck:

```
render("my_rmarkdown.Rmd", html_document(pandoc_args = "--self-contained"))
```

So, why is this happening?  It must be the way that Rmarkdown is packaging and rendering the files.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because pandoc is not programmed to search inside script tags for resources to embed.

Therefore, one option is to embed the resource yourself. Fortunately, {knitr} has a function `img_uri()` that will read and base encode the image data for us.

First, make a "main.fmt" file in your "js" directory that contains the following:

```
var special_content = '<div class="col-md-10">' + 
                            '<h2 class="mb-3">%s</h2>' +    
                            '<p>' +
                                '%s' +
                            '</p>' +
                            '<p class="viz-photo">' +             
                                '<div class="col-12">' + 
                                    '<img class="img-fluid viz" src="%s" alt="Card image cap">' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</p>' +
                          '</div>' 


$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#my_button').on('click', function(e) {

  
  document.getElementById("od-content").innerHTML = special_content;
  });
});
```

Notice that this file contains your original javascript, but the special title header, text, and image src have been replaced with "%s"'s. We will use R's `sprintf()` to read this as a template and replace the "%s"'s with the text we actually want.

Next, insert the following code chunk in your "my_rmarkdown.RMD" file:

````
```{r}
h <- "Special Title!"
p <- "Blah blah"
i <- knitr::image_uri("img/image_2.png")
f <- paste(readLines("js/main.fmt"), collapse = "\n")
writeLines(sprintf(f, h, p, i), "js/main.js")
```
````

Now, you can knit the document as you were doing before. During the knitting process, R will write you a new "main.js" file starting with the template and replacing the "%s"'s with the desired values. Notably, the img src value will now contain the base 64 encoded value that will embed your second image into the document.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this worked!  A couple questions though: 1) when using writeLines, does the order of the variables i.e. f, h, p, i have to correspond with the order of the %s statements in the FMT file?  Otherwise, how would it know where to plug in the strings?  2) This solution failed until I removed all console.log statements and commented sections from the FMT file.  If the FMT file converts to javascript, I'm wondering why comments cause it to fail.. thanks!

Comment: Yes, `sprintf()` replaces the '%s's in order. I am not entirely sure why the console.log and comments made the solution fail. My best guess would be that you were using comments with `\*` and `*\ ` which might have been interpreted as special characters during the read and then the special character version was written to the javascript as opposed to verbatim text causing the javascript to fail when run.

Comment: thanks! hmm, I was using // as is typical in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the rendered html it's making use of a base64 encoded string instead of the image source.

Ideas you could try:

- Locate if there is a public folder in your hosting. Usually all content in there can be accessed.
- Load both images at the same time. You can set one image to display: none and swap this out.
- Encode both images and instead of swapping out the link to the image, swap out the encoded string.

You're making use of jquery so you can make use of the .toggle() method. That could look something like this

```js
$('#my_button').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#img-container-1").toggle();
    $("#img-container-2").toggle();
});
```

where the element with the `#img-container-2` has `style="display: none"` applied to it by default.